# "Cannot read property '0' of null"

Tags: javascript, gwt, linechart

I'm getting this error when I want to add a LineChart widget in GWT:
"Cannot read property '0' of null"

In fact, I wrote the program at work and it runs without any problem. However, it does not run in my personal (although I use the same libraries and environment). When I just click createChartButton, my chart appears at work. But this error arises in my personal PC. What can be the mistake that I miss?

TestChart.ui.xml:

```
<g:Button ui:field="createChartButton" text="Create Chart" />
<g:VerticalPanel ui:field="chartPanel" visible="false" />
```

ChartView.java:

```
@UiHandler("createChartButton")
public void onCreateChartButtonClick(ClickEvent event){
    if(presenter != null){
        chart = presenter.onCreateChartButtonClicked(event); // Prepares a line chart and returns it.

        this.chartPanel.clear();
        this.chartPanel.add(chart);
        this.chartPanel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: make a pretty compile and preserve stacktraces, then you will see the linenumber.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach I cannot see any exception or error when I run it. I see only this warning on my browser: Cannot read property '0' of null. Is there anywhere I can see the error? by the way, even if I try to only a simple linechart, then this error raises.